# How to select the first element in a php loop and apply a class to it?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code for table in Wordpress.I want to add a class to the first element of the  loop. How can I do that. produces series of td elements, how can I change the code so that a class is added only to the first td in tr loop.

```
$table = get_field( 'hosting_plan_table' );

if ( $table ) {

echo '<tbody>';

foreach ( $table['body'] as $tr ) {

    echo '<tr>';

        foreach ( $tr as $td ) {

            echo '<td><span id="dottedunderlinet" class="'.$td['c'].'"> ';
                echo $td['c'];
            echo '</td>';
        }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
 if ( $table ) {

            echo '<tbody>';

                foreach ( $table['body'] as $tr ) {

                    echo '<tr>';

                      $class='first';

                        foreach ( $tr as $td ) {

                            echo '<td class="'.$class.'"><span id="dottedunderlinet" class="'.$td['c'].'"> ';
                                echo $td['c'];
                            echo '</td>';

                         $class='';
                        }

                    echo '</tr>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. I have set up a variable called `$i`. Within the foreach loop I add 1 to `$i`. This means that the first time the loop runs then `$i` is equal to zero. The `!$i` test is then matched and `$class` can be set to be the name of the class you want to apply.

```
$table = get_field( 'hosting_plan_table' );

$i = 0;

if ( $table ) {

echo '<tbody>';

foreach ( $table['body'] as $tr ) {

    echo '<tr>';

        foreach ( $tr as $td ) {

            if(!$i) { $class = 'some-class'; } else { $class = ''; }

            echo '<td><span id="dottedunderlinet" class="'.$class.'"> ';
                echo $td['c'];
            echo '</td>';
        }

    echo '</tr>';

    $i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ( $tr as $td ) {
  if($counter == 0){
    echo '<td class="my-custom-class-here"><span id="dottedunderlinet" class="'.$td['c'].'"> ';
  } else {
    echo '<td><span id="dottedunderlinet" class="'.$td['c'].'"> ';
  }
  echo $td['c'];
  echo '</td>';
  $counter++;
}
```